# Continuing subsection after \hformbar

Tags: errors

I'm writing an article with subsections and equations. i want to divide the equations into the line \hformbar, but after that i want to continue the numerating of subsections or the sections. Anyone can help me?

Comment: please clarify you question, what is `\hformbar`  ? it does not appear   to  be a standard latex command.

Comment: I'm using overleaf, i'm new in Latex

Comment: overleaf runs a standard latex insatllation, but I have been maintaining latex for 30 years and have never seen a command `\hformbar`  so your question is completely impossible to understand: you show no code and do not describe what input you have or what output you want, just that it uses some command that you do not say how it is defined.  make a small one page document that produces the wrong output and then describe what output you want from the test document and someone will probably help, otherwise the question will probably just be closed as unclear